# Эффект колокола (шевеление) как сделать?

Tags: animate, анимация, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Все знают, как работает обычный колокольчик! Хочу сделать визуальный эффект, который бы выглядел, как шатающийся колокол.

[image]

Чтобы колокол качался по типу маятника: верхняя часть на месте, а нижняя его часть типа покачивалась.

**Как сделать? Может, кто знает уже решение?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот в точности, что вам нужно http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/ring-a-bell-with-css-keyframe-animations/

Comment: Хорошее решение, но js бы был как бы надежнее... ну, мне так кажется.

Answer (score -2):

Поворачивай картинку вокруг верхней точки. Или поставь gif. Или заменяй картинки последовательно - наклон влево, центр, наклон вправо, центр и т.д.

Comment: Как это работать должно, я понимаю, но как сделать такой скрипт, не понимаю.

Comment: Создай gif-анимацию и не заморачивайтесь с программированием. Качаться будет везде одинаково, без проблем.

Comment: @Get, качаться-то будет, но выглядеть будет как г-но. Я бы порекомендовал SVG и CSS transitions.

Comment: Как сделаешь - так и будет выглядеть. Решения надо подбирать под конкретные задачи и Gif-анимация является в данном случае самым широким решением. Что будешь делать в IE7 с SVG и CSS-анимацией, мне непонятно.

Comment: @Get, зачем поддерживать браузер, который больше не поддерживается даже разработчиками?

Comment: @Get, сорри, IE7 еще поддерживается в Window Server 2008. Но это не отменяет того факта, что его доля -- мизерная.

Comment: Вы никогда не сталкивались с работой в организациях, где установка собственного ПО запрещена? Не общались с бухгалтерами? IE7 жив и продолжает устанавливаться на ПК вместе со старыми версиями Windows. Серьезные компании продолжают разработку сайтов, учитывая работу сайтов в IE7, пусть и не полноценную.

Comment: @Get, "Серьезные компании продолжают разработку сайтов, учитывая работу сайтов в IE7, пусть и не полноценную" -- согласен, минимальная поддержка нужна. Но на качающийся колокольчик можно забить.